# Проблема с присваиванием переменных или с методом?

Tags: javascript, строки

Почему считается ниже код **уже** неправильным, если обе переменные -- это строки больше 5 символов?

```
    if (newTest.substring(0, 2)==fullTest.substring(0, 2))
```

Comment: substring вырезает строку по данным позициям. Проверьте, чему у вас равны newTest и fullTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let newTest = 'test1';
let fullTest = 'test2';

if (newTest.substring(0, 2) == fullTest.substring(0, 2)) {
  console.log('success')
}
```

Если переменные newTest и fullTest заданы правильно, код отработает корректно